# Can I stop the service which is started by bindService instead of StartService in android?

Tags: android, android-service

I have this "Activity 1" binded to Service. I started the service using

```
Intent wrapperServiceIntent = new Intent(mContext,BleWrapper.class);
bindService(wrapperServiceIntent,mBLEWrapperServiceConnection,BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

Can I stop this service using

```
stopService(new Intent(mContext,BleWrapper.class));
```

insted of

```
mContext.unbindService(mServiceConnection);
```

Is the above scenario possible?

Answer (score 1):

From documentation:

When a service is unbound from all clients, the Android system destroys it (unless it was also started with onStartCommand()). As such, you don't have to manage the lifecycle of your service if it's purely a bound service—the Android system manages it for you based on whether it is bound to any clients.

However, if you choose to implement the onStartCommand() callback method, then you must explicitly stop the service, because the service is now considered to be started. In this case, the service runs until the service stops itself with stopSelf() or another component calls stopService(), **regardless of whether it is bound to any clients**.

Answer (score 0):

No you can not do it instead, you need to remove the bindings first.

The Android documentation says:

> Note that if a stopped service still has ServiceConnection objects bound to it with the BIND_AUTO_CREATE set, it will not be destroyed until all of these bindings are removed.

Another thing, in `stopService` you need to pass `mServiceConnection` instead of creating a new intent.

Comment: We can only pass `Intent` in `stopService`